# Python: Multiprocessing is_alive is False and exit_code is 0 and join did not worked

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am doing an experiment in multiprocess

```
import multiprocessing
import random, time
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
logging.basicConfig(
    handlers=[RotatingFileHandler('log.txt')],level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

TIMEOUT = 5

PID = None

def target_function(queue_1):
    sleep_value = random.choice(range(5,10))
    time.sleep(sleep_value)
    print('target_function', sleep_value)
    logger.info(f'target_function {sleep_value}')
    queue_1.put(True)


def t1():
    print('###############')
    logger.info('###############')
    queue_1 = multiprocessing.Queue()
    queue_value = False

    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=target_function, args=(queue_1, ))
    process.daemon = True
    process.start()
    PID = process.pid
    
    time.sleep(TIMEOUT)
    
    if not queue_1.empty():
        queue_value = queue_1.get(timeout=3)

    print(PID, queue_value)
    logger.info(f'PID: {queue_value}')

    queue_1.close()

    process.join()

    print(PID, process.is_alive(), process.exitcode)
    logger.info(f'PID: {process.is_alive()}, {process.exitcode}')

    del process


t1()
t1()
```

I called the `t1` multiple times, In that I got this result

```
###############
36049 False
36049 False 0
###############
36100 False
target_function 6
target_function 9
36100 False 0
```

Here, I printed to check whether the process is alive or not and also the exitcode

if the exitcode is 0, then the process is joined successfully.

I got the result, where the process is not alive and the exitcode is 0.

And, the queue should be closed before the process join to the main thread.

Here, the print statement in `target_function` for PID `36049` got executed after the next process started. This is because of the `time.sleep`.

But, the `join()` did not waited for the complete execution of `target_function`, and moves on

What is the reason for this, why the `join()` did not wait for the execution of print statement in `target_function`

Thanks

EDIT: MORE INFO

the program is actually using the logging module for the output, For easier reading, I made the script with `print` statement,
The actual output from the `log.txt` looks like this

```
INFO:__main__:###############
INFO:__main__:36049 False
INFO:__main__:36049 False 0
INFO:__main__:###############
INFO:__main__:36100 False
INFO:__main__:target_function 6
INFO:__main__:target_function 9
INFO:__main__:36100 False 0
```

I cant reproduce the same output, I got this type of output few times when I run this script multiple times

When I tried to creating this output, I run this code multiple times, to see if the same kind of output generates or not, and I got same kind of output in the `log.txt`

```
INFO:__main__:2023-05-22 14:31:33.922080 ###############
INFO:__main__:2023-05-22 14:31:38.955622 PID: False
INFO:__main__:2023-05-22 14:31:40.958825 PID: True, None
INFO:__main__:2023-05-22 14:31:40.959761 ###############
INFO:__main__:2023-05-22 14:31:43.637320 target_function 9
INFO:__main__:2023-05-22 14:31:45.966851 PID: False
INFO:__main__:2023-05-22 14:31:47.316978 target_function 6
INFO:__main__:2023-05-22 14:31:47.614102 PID: False, 0
```

From the above output also, the `.join()` does not wait for the process to complete

Comment: If the sleep duration in target_function is greater than 5 seconds then the queue will be empty when you test it in t1(). Therefore the output will be False. I have no idea why you think the join() didn't work. You do not need to explicitly close the queue as the close() function will be called when the reference to the queue is garbage collected. After P.join() you can assert that P.is_alive() == False

Comment: @DarkKnight: The `print('target_function', sleep_value)` in the worker process should execute before `process.join()` finishes, which should happen before `print(PID, process.is_alive(), process.exitcode)`, but the displayed output seems to indicate something else is going on.

Comment: @vishak: How are you running this? Is the output going to a terminal directly? You're not flushing your prints, so depending on the output buffering, there could be some reordering of printed output between different processes... but I wouldn't expect *this* much reordering, and I can't reproduce this degree of reordering either.

Comment: @user2357112, after your comment explaining about the flushing in prints, I edited the question which has more info. I actually got this output in the log file using the logging module, not in the terminal directly. For easier&faster understanding the script, I changed the logging module to print statement in the question. Please go through the question it once again, thanks

Comment: It might help if you explained what output you were expecting.

Comment: @DarkKnight, I am just trying to understanding the flow of multiprocessing. In that, I found that join is not worked properly

Comment: are you running it from outside any IDE ?? My IDE behaves strangly when I dont reset kernel between runs of the same script